# mysql error : ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, permissions

when i try to view the databases in mysql i get this error:

```
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)
```

And that stops my app from displaying...

My django debugger says:

```
(2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/my_database' (13)")
```

Here is my settings file :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'my_database',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'root',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '****',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '3306',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
```

What can cause the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you been connected previously? Can you edit in your settings file so we can get a better idea of what is happening please?

Comment: Maybe this could be of use, in case your system uses AppArmor:http://ar.zu.my/solved-show-databases-error-1018-hy000-can-t-read-dir-of-errno-13/

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You need to set ownership and permissions for directory:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/ #your mysql user may have different name
chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

Note: `-R` makes commands recursive - you may omit it, if there is no subdirs in `/var/lib/mysql/`.

Comment: should i replace the first mysql with my mysql user?

Comment: the user under which your `mysqld` daemon is run - see in `/etc/passwd`. I believe it is `mysql` by default

Comment: ive changed it and it works but now it works but if i reload it doesnt... and if i reload again it does

Comment: @TonyKyriakidis have you restarted `mysqld`? (`service mysqld restart`)

Comment: You will also need to change apparmor settings and reload it. This is a 2012 answer and I am not sure if apparmor was enforced then, but I had the same problem and this answer alone did not help. Fixing apparmor profile did the job. Edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` and `sudo service apparmor reload`.

Comment: needed this after accidentally mounting my host mysql dir on a docker container, it changed the user ID to `polkitd`.

Comment: I changed the owner to myslq by  chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql without restarting the mysql. Thanks

Answer (score 37):

This should work for Mac users:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/
sudo chmod -R 755 /usr/local/mysql/
```

If this doesn't work, try running `which mysql` to see where your mysql installation is located, and then replace `/usr/local/mysql/` in the command above with whatever is before the 'bin' directory.

For example, on my system `which mysql` produces the following output:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

so my path is `/usr/local/mysql/`

Comment: I found this with Google and while I was able to use the answer to fix my problem, I had different paths. So I posted this for the benefit of other mac users that might end up here.

Comment: It seems to be relocated in El Capitan under macports.  I had to use

sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /opt/local/var/db/mysql56/ 

sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /opt/local/var/run/mysql56/ 

sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /opt/local/var/log/mysql56/

Comment: Thanks. This helped me after upgrading to El Capitan.

Comment: also on OS X here (Mavericks 10.9) - my mysql user was `_mysql`. you can find out your user (and mysql install dir) with `ps aux |grep mysql`.

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS/RedHat, you should do the same thing on a different path:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /data/mysql/
chmod -R 755 /data/mysql/
```

Comment: my `/data/` is empty on centos 7

Answer (score 1):

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/

chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mysql/
```

I can confirm that these two chmod statements worked for me (Webmin didn't see the databases nor did show tables) but I'm not sure why I had to do this after setting up perhaps two dozen servers (Centos) with MySQL in that past few years.

Comment: Why have you added the same answer as @scriptin only to say that it works but you didn't know what they actually do. Better put a comment in the other answer and upvote it (if you can). It's a bad idea to suggest to others things that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

osx high sierra use the following command solves the issue:

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

if you installed mariadb using homebrew you can run the following the command for OS X

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/var/mysql/
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mysql/
```