# mysql: ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.'

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, dir

I'm trying to set a different data directory for mysql (OS Ubuntu 12.04), e.g. `/mnt/mysql/mysql`.

I'm executing:

```
sudo mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/mnt/mysql/mysql
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
mysql -uroot
```

The thing is that the query `SHOW DATABASES;` gives `ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)`, but queries like `SHOW TABLES FROM mysql` are working fine.

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066411/mysql-error-error-1018-hy000-cant-read-dir-of-errno-13

Comment: The question is identical, @CRRaD. If you couldn't get the existing solution to work, post a comment requesting clarification on how to apply it, or offer a bounty to attract more answers. Don't simply repost the question as that helps nobody. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I met the exactly same problem. The owner and permission of mysqldata folder are correct. But it still said: mysql: ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.'

I had been struggling with it for whole day. at the end I worked it out.
Please check `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` file. 
it should be `/data/mysql/ r`, instead. I missed out a **forward slash**.

After I changed(vi /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld)

```
    /data/mysql r,
    /data/mysql/** rwk,
```

to (**don't miss the slash**)

```
    /data/mysql/ r,
    /data/mysql/** rwk,
```

Then restart AppArmor and mysql.

```
    sudo service apparmor restart
    sudo service mysql restart
```

After that the error was gone!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a permission issue. Possible fix:

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /mnt/mysql/mysql
```

Comment: what if everything is owned by mysql:mysql already and it's also chmoded 777, how come it can't read?