# ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './<db>/' (errno: 13) - *not* a permission issue

Tags: mysql

Today I updated openssl (due to the recent heartbleed vulnerability) and all of a sudden mysql is acting strangely. I was recently able to modify tables, but now when I try to add a column I get:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table '#sql-34f_872b' (errno: 13)
```

And trying to do `show tables` results in:

```
ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of './<db>/' (errno: 13)
```

During the openssl upgrade there was a prompt asking about an upgrade to mysql. It was asking if I want to keep my current /etc/my.cnf or if I wanted to replace with the new one - I selected to *keep*.

Typically this would be a permissions issue, and I've tried and tested the permissions on the mysql `datadir` (using [this answer from a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11066467/22617)).

A few other strange things:

- When I try these commands, I'm using the mysql command client and logged in as root
- I *am* able to insert new rows into existing tables

I feel like the openssl upgrade is too much of a coincidence to ignore, and I'm not keen on the idea of restarting mysqld without really knowing that the server will definitely come back up (since there's an unknown issue going on here).

Any ideas?

---

Reply to comments and questions:

Output of `ls -ltrFa`:

```
remy@ip-10-168-9-52:~$ ls -ltrFa /vol/mysql/
total 49367084
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql           0 Feb 11  2013 debian-5.5.flag*
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Feb 11  2013 test/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Feb 11  2013 performance_schema/
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Feb 11  2013 mysql/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql           6 Feb 11  2013 mysql_upgrade_info*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql          25 Feb 12  2013 slave-relay-bin.index*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql         126 Feb 12  2013 slave-relay-bin.000001*
drwxr-xr-x 6 mysql mysql        4096 Oct 14 14:35 ./
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql        4096 Apr  3 15:50 jsbin/
drwxrwxrwx 5 root  root         4096 Apr  9 16:07 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql 50417631232 Apr  9 17:24 ibdata1*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql    67108864 Apr  9 17:24 ib_logfile0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql    67108864 Apr  9 17:25 ib_logfile1*
```

Output of `ps aux | grep mysql`:

```
mysql      847  1.4 83.9 16342212 14681964 ?   Ssl   2013 3646:34 /usr/sbin/mysqld
remy      4038  0.0  0.0 101816  2824 pts/0    S+   16:58   0:00 mysql -uroot -px xxxxx jsbin
```

Note that I've also tried running mysql using `sudo -u mysql mysql -uroot -pxxx jsbin` and it results in the same issue.

Here is the the log from the `apt-get upgrade openssl` which shows mysql being included in the update: https://gist.github.com/remy/10291829

Server is ubuntu-precise-12.04-amd64 (installations are all via apt-get rather than manually compiled).

Versions of mysql:

```
$ mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.35, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

Comment: There's no way that this is actually related to OpenSSL in any way, shape or form.  What OS on what platform?  Are you using the OS-provided packages, someone else's packages, or are you doing a custom compile?  Are you using the OS-defined data directory, or a custom location?

Comment: Can you post the `ls -l` output of your mysql data dir? And check which user is running mysqld using `ps aux | grep mysql`?

Comment: Here's my apt-get history for the openssl update, and you can see updates to mysql: https://gist.github.com/remy/10291829

Comment: @RemySharp, what I mean is, this isn't an actual OpenSSL problem.  So, from the update log, you're using an Ubuntu version?  My guess was going to be a Redhat-based distro with SELinux enabled and busted security labeling... What are the actual ownership and permissions on the data directory itself?

Comment: @charles I've updated with the full perms, and added the server: Ubuntu 12.04 x64.

Comment: I feel like this might be more closely linked to the issue, but it's not the cause: http://ar.zu.my/solved-show-databases-error-1018-hy000-can-t-read-dir-of-errno-13/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out that `apt-get upgrade openssl` actually upgrades everything else in it's wake - along with openssl. So somehow MySQL got caught in that update.

**By accident** (an AWS backup actually) the machine was rebooted, and all problems went away.

I'm pretty sure this is because some of MySQL's libraries had been updated, but the server that was loaded in memory was somehow incompatible.

I wouldn't generally recommend a random restart to fix these issues, but in this particular situation, it did the job.

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me :

```
rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*

/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Answer (score 0):

The most-likely reason I can think of for this is due to some upgrade process or script trying to alter table defaults and/or one of the dependent tools adding a table and immediately altering it. This could step on a documented limitation in MySQL that prevents you from adding and dropping foreign keys in the same ALTER statement.:
* http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68286

Can you check your logs to see what was running when the failure happened and then manually edit the update script or manually make the change so it's skipped?

I think keeping your my.cnf was the right way to go too. But if you can't get enough info from the logs as noted above, you could try disabling FK checks in there, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

...that does risk some trash data though, so use as a last resort.

---

As for OpenSSL, this was triggered by the update but not specific to OpenSSL. Any update to 5.5.29 that ran a complex ALTER might have triggered this

Comment: Would that explain why I can't do `show tables` (as it gives similar errors)

Comment: I'm not sure why `show tables` wouldn't work, but it could have been related to the tables being in some sort of detached or rebuild state. As for your post below ... totally right that a random rebuild shouldn't be the solution, but I'm guessing that the DB was able to rebuild things during the reboot becuase FK checks were either suspended or the storage engine forced a check and was "smart enough" to fix itself before bringing the data online.