# MySql : ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)

Tags: php, mysql

Recently mysql crashed and I had no choice but to backup the contents of `var/lib/mysql` to `/home/backup/`and re-install the database.

after re-installing mysql server,

1. renamed `/var/lib/mysql to mysql.orig`
2. in /var/lib, I made a directory mysql
3. moved the contents from the `home/backup` folder to /var/lib/mysql

Now by running `mysql -u user -p` and when I call `show databases` It give s the following error :

> MySql : ERROR 1018 (HY000): Can't read dir of '.' (errno: 13)

How to solve this?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066411/mysql-error-error-1018-hy000-cant-read-dir-of-errno-13

Answer (score 3):

For future users. Two more steps are needed: 
1. chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/
2. service mysql restart

And you are done! All your databases are back.